# Displaying multiple ggvis plots simultaneously?

Tags: r, shiny

I have two ggvis plots that I would like to display side by side in R (shiny). In the server.R file, I have

```
vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")  
vis2 %>% bind_shiny("plot2")
```

Both vis and vis2 work when displayed individually, but not together. My ui.R code to display them is

```
column(6,div(class='span12',align="center",textOutput("title")),  
        ggvisOutput("plot1"),align=left),  
column(6,div(class='span12',align="center",textOutput("title")),  
        ggvisOutput("plot2"),align=left)
```

When used together, I can't get anything to show.

Comment: Try using proper formatting to help answerers easily read and answer your question since yours is quite hard to read currently. For help on how to format see the bottom right section when editing your post.

Comment: Just signed up today. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: It's all good. We all started one day. Welcome to StackOverflow! :)